# UIViewController accessory view not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, accessoryview

I'm dealing with a weird issue in one of my projects. I'm using an accessory view attached to the bottom of a view controller so when the keyboard goes up, this accessory view. For that, I'm using this code:

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
  return self.myAccessoryView;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
  return YES;
}
```

My accessoryView is on my storyboard and linked to an IBOutlet. I'm presenting my view controller with a Segue and everything goes fine, but there is a problem when I try to present my view controller using this code

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"my_storyboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController* vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];    
[self myNavigationViewController].firstChild = vc;
```

When this happens, `canBecomeFirstResponder` and `inputAccessoryView` methods on `MyViewController` are not called, so my accessory view is not displayed.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How you are setting accessory View to textfield ?

Comment: I'm not setting the accessory view to a texfield but to the view controller itself. That can be done implementing the two methods I posted, they're from UIResponder.